# How to decorate all the comparison methods inheriting from tuple

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, python-decorators

**Problem**

Version is being expressed as string and compared at lot of places. But then "5.10"  `is less than` "5.2" due to ASCII comparison

**Solution**

Change it to `tuple` and then compare. Since comparison is at multiple places, I thought of having a custom class inheriting from `tuple` and handle the comparison myself

**Proposed code**

```
class Version(tuple):
  def __new__(self, v1):
    if not isinstance(v1, tuple):
      v1 = tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), v1.split('.')))
    return tuple.__new__(Version, v1)

  def __lt__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, tuple):
      other = tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), other.split('.')))
    return super().__lt__(other)

  def __repr__(self):
    return '.'.join(str(x) for x in self)
```

This is the code I came up with, so far, and it seems to work fine for cases like:

```
v1 = Version("5.10")
print(v1 < "5.2")
```

The question I have is, how can I avoid doing the same thing for all the other methods `__le__`, `__gt__` etc.

There should be a more pythonic way to just massage the `other` argument and convert it to `tuple`, then call the base class corresponding method

Comment: If you used _composition_, rather than _inheritance_, you could use [`total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).

Comment: So I need to define `__eq__` and `__lt__` and `total_ordering` will replicate it for me ?

Comment: The only reason I was using _inheritance_ was to use `__lt__` from `tuple`. I can surely switch to _composition_ instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, changed *inheritance* to *composition* and used `total_ordering`

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Version():
  def __init__(self, v1):
    self.v1 = tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), v1.split('.')))

  def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, tuple):
      other = tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), other.split('.')))
    return self.v1 == other

  def __lt__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, tuple):
      other = tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), other.split('.')))
    return self.v1 < other

  def __repr__(self):
    return '.'.join(str(x) for x in self.v1)
```